# Can't find Menu ID

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

1)This is Code declare my id at menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="HOME"/>

    <item
        android:id="category"
        android:icon="@drawable/category"
        android:title="CATEGORY"/>

    <item
        android:id="basket"
        android:icon="@drawable/basket"
        android:title="BASKET"/>

    <item
        android:id="me"
        android:icon="@drawable/me"
        android:title="ME"/>

</menu>
```

2. This is code i call my id

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigation =

            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.home:
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "HOME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case R.id.category:
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "HOME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                    }

                    return true;

                }

            };
```

I have error when i call category id
`case R.id.category:`

but at `case R.id.home:` ,the code is right means no wrong.

Question : Who know why i cannot call my id?

can anyone give suggest for me, i take long time to fix this code. mybe i miss something like dot or comma? hahahaha

Comment: show how do you set your `menu.xml` for `BottomNavigationView`. Are you using `app:menu="@menu/menu"`?

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<item android:id="home"
```

should be

```
  <item android:id="@+id/home"
```

the same applies to the others

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with all the ids in your menu XML file
change it to the following:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    item android:id="@+id/home"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"
    android:title="HOME"/>

<item
    item android:id="@+id/category"
    android:icon="@drawable/category"
    android:title="CATEGORY"/>

<item
    item android:id="@+id/basket"
    android:icon="@drawable/basket"
    android:title="BASKET"/>

<item
    item android:id="@+id/me"
    android:icon="@drawable/me"
    android:title="ME"/>

</menu>
```